# Problem installing Radeon Driver

Tags: drivers, video, radeon

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 model 5547 with a AMD Radeon HD R7 M265.
With a clean installation of Arch Linux (I've tried installing Debian too, without success.) I tried installing the open-source drivers, but I've got the `no screens found` error.
Now I tried installing the proprietary drivers (and the "hybrid Intel/AMD graphics card" section of the wiki too).
I already have the module `fglrx` loading, an Xorg config from `aticonfig --initial`

But when I run `fglrxinfo` it says `Error: unable to open display (null)`

My `lspci` output:

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265]
```

Comment: Just now I installed this driver https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics
And it worked!
But I want to know if this is right...

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you had any luck getting the r7 m265 to work under Arch? My laptop is exactly same as yours and I am also using it with the intel drivers currently. I have been searching for a while now to get the open source drivers to work but it seems support for r7 m265 hasn't come yet. Also a lot of confusion regarding the names. According to AMD's site, the proprietary drivers should work. But I have been unsuccessful in getting it to run using Vi0l0's repo (plus, that supports only X server 1.15 and I am currently using 1.16)... Any help/info would be much appreciated...

Comment: I opened a post in the Arch Linux Forum, you can check it out :) https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190236